# ctypes - passing a struct with a pointer to another struct

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

In my C code I have:

```
typedef struct{
    int info1;
    int info2;
    MoreData* md;
} BasicData;

typedef struct{
    int extinfo[100];
    char stuff[100];
} MoreData;
```

Now I have a C library function which takes BasicData as argument and I want to call it from Python.
To do this I construct a ctypes class:

```
class BasicData(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("info1", c_int),
                ("info2", c_int),
                ("md", ??????)]
```

My question is what do I fill into ???? space to be able to pass this struct to C function (or do I need something completely different?). MoreData is just used during computations and I don't need to read from it in my Python code so allocating memory for it will be handled from C library level. I just need to pass a BasicData struct with correct pointer type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to allocate or use the `MoreData` struct, then `md` is just a generic pointer as far as ctypes is concerned. Use a `void *` -- i.e. `c_void_p`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `class MoreData(Structure)` wrapping the other struct. Then pass that as `("md", POINTER(MoreData))`.

C guarantees that the struct fields are allocated in order, so if you really don't want to access `md` from Python then you can just not specify it in `_fields_` (since it comes last). Then ctypes will believe that you have a struct with only the first two members.

Ctypes is fine for a one-off access to a C structure, but if you are routinely tying together C code with Python then I would really recommend you check out Cython.

Edit: As eryksun pointed out (feeble pun), I forgot the POINTER.

Comment: I read the question as the `BasicData` struct is allocated by ctypes and passed to a function. In that case, it needs at least a `c_void_p` there. If one did define the `MoreData` struct, the field would be `("md", POINTER(MoreData))`.

Comment: Agree, depends on whether there is any C code that accesses `md`